# I want a fade in and out animation that stops inbetween

Tags: html, css

I am working on a home page for a school project and I want to have fade in and out transitions between a few paragraphs and titles but the thing is I need it to stay on the page for a few seconds and not just fade right in and out so that the user can read it,

here's the code what I try but it seems doesn't work properly:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.WelcomeMenu {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/4plHDVeTkWuFMihxQnzBSb/aea2f06d675c3d710d095306e377382f/shutterstock_554314555_copy.jpg ');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.WelcomeMenu h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 16%;
  padding-left: 7%;
}

.WelcomeMenu h1:after {
  content: '\2713';
}

#think:after {
  content: '\01F4A1';
}

.WelcomeMenu h2 {
  font-size: 23px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 7%;
  padding-top: 0.8%;
  color: #fff;
}

.WelcomeMenu p {
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 7%
}

.Fade1 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="WelcomeMenu">
  <div class="Fade1">
    <h1> 
      <span style="font-weight: 1000;color: #F10000; font-size: 64px;">STOP</span>
      <span style="font-weight: 600;" id="think">THINK </span>
      <span style=" font-weight: 600;"> & CHECK</span>
    </h1>
    <p>
      Have you ever wondered how factual the news you just <br> scrolled past on TikTok are? Do you wanna learn how to <br> fact check the information your favorite artists are spreading?
    </p>
    <h2> Check out this page to learn more!
      <h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the timeline and add more keyframes so it will fade in, sit for about 10 seconds and then fade out.   See snippet.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
    }


    .WelcomeMenu {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/4plHDVeTkWuFMihxQnzBSb/aea2f06d675c3d710d095306e377382f/shutterstock_554314555_copy.jpg ');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .WelcomeMenu h1 {
      font-size: 45px;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #ffff;
      padding: 0;
      padding-top: 16%;
      padding-left: 7%;
    }

    .WelcomeMenu h1:after {
      content: '\2713';
    }

    #think:after {
      content: '\01F4A1';
    }

    .WelcomeMenu h2 {
      font-size: 23px;
      background-color: transparent;
      padding-left: 7%;
      padding-top: 0.8%;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .WelcomeMenu p {
      color: #ffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 1%;
      padding-left: 7%
    }

    .Fade1 {
      -webkit-animation: fadeinout 12s linear forwards;
      animation: fadeinout 12s linear forwards;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      10% {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes fadeinout {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      10% {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title> uydvujdhbv</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <script src='main.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="WelcomeMenu">
    <div class="Fade1">
      <h1> <span style="font-weight: 1000;color: #F10000; font-size: 64px;"> STOP! </span>
        <span style="font-weight: 600;" id="think">THINK </span>
        <span style=" font-weight: 600;"> & CHECK</span>
      </h1>
      <p>
        Have you ever wondered how factual the news you just <br> scrolled past on TikTok are?
        Do you wanna learn how to <br> fact check the information your favorite artists are spreading?
      </p>

      <h2> Check out this page to learn more!<h2>

    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```